# ReactJS - setting variable from 2 separate useState

Tags: reactjs, jsx

#### Background

I am attempting to set a variable based on two separate button-groups using `onClick()` to update the `useState`.

The first group will record either "data1", "data2", or "data3".

The second group will record "0", "1", or "3".

I am looking for the end result to be a variable which I can use to select which group of data to pull.

The variable should look something like this "data10". (where button 1 was selected in both groups.)

#### Current code

```JSX
  const [bigChartData, setbigChartData] = React.useState("data1");
  const setBgChartData = (name) => {
    setbigChartData(name);
    (name+bigChartTime);
  };
  const [bigChartTime, setbigChartTime] = React.useState("0");
  const setBgChartTime = (name) => {
    setbigChartTime(name);
    console.log(bigChartData+(name));
  };
```

Further down the code the following presents the dynamic data

```JSX
                <div className="chart-area">
                  <Line
                    data={chartExample1[bigChartData]}
                    options={chartExample1.options}
                  />
                </div>
```

#### The Problem

I receive the following error

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

I understand that this is telling me I can't use an expression here, but I am little lost for how to otherwise build this

#### What I've tried

- Set the `{` `}` around this but it still gives the same error.
- Set the `(` `)` around this but it still gives the same error.
- Using `console.log(name+bigChartTime);` in place of line 4, it presents the information I expect to the console without an error.

If there is anyway to workaround this or if I need to rework in a different way, all help is appreciated!

Comment: What's this `(name+bigChartTime);` and can you explain more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is kinda messy and it is not exactly clear what you want to achieve. I would suggest you to keep your state variables together and separate them from event handlers visually. Also, differentiate the event handler names from the variable state setters: `setbigChartData` and `setBgChartData` have pretty similar names which makes it pretty hard to keep track of what's going on in your code.

Now, as you've already noticed, you get the `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions` error because you're using an expression that basically does nothing: `(name+bigChartTime);`. I am not sure if you're trying to assing this to a variable or?

You need the concatenated result of both `bigChartData` and `bigChartTime`. You don't need a separate state variable for this. You should avoid introducing a separate state variable for results that are based on other state variables, especially when this result is easily calculatable. So, I would suggest for you to just use:

```
`${bigChartData}${bigChartTime}`
```

when you need the concatenated result or store in a simple **non-state** variable before using it. In the end, you just need something like this:

```
const [bigChartData, setbigChartData] = React.useState("data1");
const [bigChartTime, setbigChartTime] = React.useState("0");

const handleChartDataChange = (name) => {
    setbigChartData(name);
};

const handleChartTimeChange = (name) => {
    setbigChartTime(name);
};
```

As you haven't given more context on the usage of the concatenated result, this is generally the way to go.

---

Side note: Good job with the formatting of your question. It's a rare occurrence. You should work a bit more on the question clarity, though.

Comment: Thanks, you helped guide me to where I was going wrong.
I fixed by putting the concatenated expression into the actual element call.
`<Line data={chartExample1[bigChartData+bigChartTime]} />`